# How to turn closure from old js library into typescript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

Hello I'm trying to convert JS library into TypeScript.
Link to library: https://github.com/msarhan/hijrah-date
I found it difficult to convert main function into class. I don't understand the part that why `HijrahDate` has a `HijrahDate` function in it ? Is it old way of creating constructor ?
What I'm trying to achieve is to convert (if possible) old JS code into Typescript class.

Simplified version

```js
var HijrahDate = (function(){

  HijrahDate.isValid = isValid;
  HijrahDate.isHijrahDate = isHijrahDate;

  HijrahDate.prototype.getTime = getTime;
  HijrahDate.prototype.setFullYear = setFullYear;

  …
  init();

  function HijrahDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds){
    this._year = Number.NaN;
    this._monthOfYear = Number.NaN;
    this._dayOfMonth = Number.NaN;

    var y, m, d, g;
    …
  }

  …
  function init(){
    var years = [];
    years['1300']=[30,29,30,29,30,29,30,29,30,29,30,29];
    … //rest of years till years['1600']
    var minYear = 1300;
    var maxYear = 1600;
    var isoStart = epochDayFromGregorain(new Date(1882, 11-1, 12));
    hijrahStartEpochMonth = minYear * 12;
    minEpochDay = isoStart;
    hijrahEpochMonthStartDays = createEpochMonths(minEpochDay, minYear, maxYear, years);
    maxEpochDay = hijrahEpochMonthStartDays[hijrahEpochMonthStartDays.length - 1];

    minYearLength = 0, maxYearLength = 0;
    for (var year = minYear; year < maxYear; year++) {
        var length = _getYearLength(year);
        minYearLength = Math.min(minYearLength, length);
        maxYearLength = Math.max(maxYearLength, length);
    }
    …
  }
  return HijrahDate;

})();
...
```

I've tried so far to create a class with contructor which has init inside

```js
export class HijrahDate {
    year: number;
    monthOfYear: number;
    dayOfMonth: number;
    hours?: number;
    minutes?: number;
    private _gregorianDate: any;
    private _monthOfYear: any;
    private _dayOfMonth: any;
    seconds?: number;
    milliseconds?: number;

    constructor(
        year: number,
        monthOfYear: number,
        dayOfMonth: number,
        hours?: number,
        minutes?: number,
        seconds?: number,
        milliseconds?: number
    ) {
        this.year = year;
        this.monthOfYear = monthOfYear;
        this.dayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
        this._gregorianDate = new Date();
        this.init();
    }
```

Comment: You haven't show what `init` does, so we can't tell whether you should call it from your constructor.

Comment: "*I don't understand the part that why HijrahDate has a HijrahDate function in it?*" - have a look at the module pattern. Most likely the actual structure of the code is not two `HijrahDate` functions, but an IEFE.

Comment: Okay thank you, now I know it's called IIFE, I've updated the code, basically the init function is giant array(don't know why it has string as index) which represent number of moths from year 1300 to 1600, so I add shortened version of it.

Comment: What's still dubious though is that in the original code the `init` function is called outside of the `function HijrahDate(…)` constructor but in your new code it's called within. Iff it's IIFE (your code excerpt is inconclusive given the ellipsis), that would need to be static code. Maybe you could also link the full code?

Comment: Sure I will add link to the top of the post, code has some wierd parts for example array where the indexes are string like years["1300"]. https://github.com/msarhan/hijrah-date

Comment: Thanks. That `init` function is rather pointless in that IIFE, it could (should) have been directly inlined at the place where it is called. Since you're probably not just converting everything to a class, but also converting it to module syntax, you should just put all those "private" static variables as constants in your module scope (outside of the `class`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript implementation generates the class through an IIFE, which effectively provides a pattern for generating a 'private' API without prior native support. The `init` function itself could be considered part of the private API. While invoked, it's never actually exposed on the returned class. Further, `init` relies on certain private vars such as `maxEpochDay` which you have not declared.

Any function or variable not ultimately exposed on the returned class via the IIFE could be declared private with ts. Those which are defined on the prototype property in the IIFE could be included be added as class methods, which are public by default or can be marked for clarity.